# Django: Model class user.models.Users doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Django version: 2.0
Python: 3.6.5
Error: Model class user.models.Users doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
I have just add model Users to my views.

base.py:

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites'
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'clockingIn.users.apps.UserConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic

from .models import Users


class UsersList(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    raise_exception = True
    model = Users

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ""


class UsersDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    raise_exception = True
    model = Users

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ""
```

model.py:

```
class Users(AbstractUser):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(_('uuid'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=127, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=127, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=127, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.Users'` in your `settings.py`

Comment: What is the full name of the app that your models.py belongs to? This module should be in your LOCAL_APPS. I see "clockingIn.users.apps.UserConfig", but you haven't told us if that's the module in question. Would be helpful to see that file though, if it's relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the issue was that i have forgot the "clockingIn" before user in config/urls.py:
`url(r'^users/', include('clockingIn.users.urls'))`