# RuntimeError: Model class xxx.xxx doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

i am getting the following error when trying to run the django 2 app

few lines from stacktrace

> File
>   "/Users/shobi/Projects/emailtool/emailtool/frontend/models/AwsSettings.py",
>   line 4, in
>
> from emailtool.frontend.models.AwsRegions import AwsRegions   File "/Users/shobi/Projects/emailtool/emailtool/frontend/models/AwsRegions.py",
>   line 4, in
>
> class AwsRegions(models.Model):   File "/Users/shobi/Projects/emailtool/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>
> line 108, in **new**
>
> "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name) RuntimeError: Model class emailtool.frontend.models.AwsRegions.AwsRegions doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

I tried

[Django: Model class user.models.Users doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257101/django-model-class-user-models-users-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label-and)

[RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388637/runtimeerror-model-class-django-contrib-sites-models-site-doesnt-declare-an-ex)

and many google results as well, what is missing?

Django2, Python 3.6

**Edit:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'frontend',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: What does your `INSTALLED_APPS` look like?

Comment: Check out the Django tutorial. You have to put your app in the settings.py

Comment: Did you added `app_name = 'app_name'` in urls.py of that app ?

Comment: @PankajSharma, No i havent added that

Comment: Have  a look at - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28691

Comment: @PankajSharma That is not related i think, and that doesn't solve my probelm as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figured it out after trying all the possible Stackoverflow answers.**

In some of my views/forms I was requiring this model called **AwsRegions**, Initially all the models were inside a single file which later moved to a separate folder called `models/` and I updated the other existing code which was requiring this class.

After some time the problem which is specified in the question came while trying the `runserver` command. (I suppose the pycache was giving older files before, so it was not throwing any error.).

But this error was not making any sense at all.

Then I tried to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command, and it started throwing errors, then I went and fixed those errors, those were simple file not found errors due to invalid paths. after that i tried `python3 manage.py runserver` and it ran successfully.

So, In essence

1. Run `python3 manage.py makemigrations`
2. Fix the incoming errors
3. Run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` again